# Using docker-compose to collaborate on existing git repo Django project

Tags: django, git, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm just getting started with Docker, and I want to use it to containerize a Django project which ~7 collaborators are working on, and I want some of us to have the option of using Docker to speed up the on-boarding process of setting up a local development environment.

The app we are working on is a Django app, using Postgres/PostGIS and some other dependencies. So far, I've followed [this tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/) which goes through creating a new Django project and using docker-compose to have it run in a container.

My question has to do with the workflow of using docker-compose with many other people to collaborate on an existing Django project. Should those of us using Docker follow a similar pattern as shown in the tutorial, but instead of creating a new project, simply clone the repository and proceed as the tutorial does?

Sorry if this question doesn't make sense. I'm just trying to get a sense if my use-case is a fit for docker/docker-compose, and if what I'm proposing is plausible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should those of us using Docker follow a similar pattern as shown in the tutorial, but instead of creating a new project, simply clone the repository and proceed as the tutorial does?

Yes. You use git just like the other developers that might not use Docker. The Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml (as shown in the tutorial) should actually be committed to your git repository. That way, you only have to write them once, and all collaborators can use them, if they want.